# Checking if an integer dataset value return dbnull value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having trouble checking if the value returned has a DBnull value in C#.

Here is my code

```
LoanDSTableAdapters.LoanApplicationsTableAdapter loanApp = 
    new LoanDSTableAdapters.LoanApplicationsTableAdapter();

LoanDS.LoanApplicationsDataTable loanAppDetails = 
    loanApp.GetLoanApplication(MySessionManager.AppID.ToString());

if (loanAppDetails.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    int newclient;
    if (!loanAppDetails[0].datNewClient == DBNull.Value)
    { 
        newclient = 1; 
    }
    else 
    { 
        newclient = Convert.ToInt32(loanAppDetails[0].datNewClient.ToString()); 
    }
```

This is the error I get and it makes me go nuts:

> Operator "!" cannot be applied to operand of type "int"

Comment: Don't go nuts. Try learning about the [C# language and its operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx).

Comment: In other words: use e.g. `loanAppDetails[0].datNewClient != DBNull.Value`.

Comment: Or use `!(loanAppDetails[0].datNewClient == DBNull.Value)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Uwe said, you need to improve your c# skills.

```
if (loanAppDetails[0].datNewClient != DBNull.Value)
```

Is the way to go. Instead, you are telling the compiler to negate an int, and then compare that to a DbNull - what just cannot be.